# Difference between definition of various insurance in Germany

Tags: germany, insurance

What is definition and difference of:

1. Travel Insurance (Eg: Mawista VIsum)
2. Student Visa Insurance (Eg:Mawista Student)
3. Government Insurance (Dak eg)

What exactly should an insurance have for it to fall under each category)

Comment: Acceptable for who?

Comment: Do you have the exact German names for these various types of insurance?

Comment: check https://www.toytowngermany.com/

Answer (score 2):

I feel you are mixing up (or they are mixing up for you, to milk money from you) the definitions of travel insurance (not compulsory, the first), health insurance (compulsory, but as a student you get a cheaper one that is only covering a bit, the second one) and pension insurance (compulsory, but sometimes there is a facultative additional one).

It is a mess, I strongly recommend you to dig into the forum's threads of this expats (immigrants, if you want to define them correctly) site https://www.toytowngermany.com/ and then come back with a self answer to your question: this will help future visitors.

Comment: I think that 'dak' is actually: [DAK-Gesundheit – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DAK-Gesundheit), which is a health supplier (Krankenkasse) and that the term 'Government Insurance' is getting mixed up with **gesetzlichen Krankenversicherung** (Statutory Health Insurance)